# C# creating Web.config file programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, configuration, web-config

I'm writing and installer for an ASP.NET application, and I have a few data fields, (connection strings, smtp servers, etc), that I want the installer to build from user input, encrypt and store in the Web.config file. The issue I am having is that both WebConfigurationManager and ConfigurationManager are both designed to work off existing configuration files. How can I construct a new configuration file, and encrypt it before saving it?

Comment: Just create an XML file.

Comment: Can I get the encryption on the xml file?

Comment: Store a minimal web.config as a resource in the installer, save it to file and then continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend starting with a base configuration file that does not contain fields you want, then using `XDocument` or `WebConfigurationManger` add the configuration information and encrypt it.

[Source: Encrypting and decrypting sensitive data in your web.config files using Protected configuration - Part IV](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/01/04/encrypting-and-decrypting-sensitive-data-in-your-web-config-files-using-protected-configuration-part-iv.aspx)

Code incase the content goes down:

```
private void EncryptConfig()
{
    // Open the Web.config file.
    Configuration config = 
        WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    // Get the connectionStrings section.
    ConnectionStringsSection section =
    config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;

    // Toggle encryption.
    if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
    }
    else
    {
    if (!section.SectionInformation.IsLocked)
    {
        section.SectionInformation
               .ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");             

        section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;             

        //Save changes to the Web.config file.       
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);           }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I took a while and I ran into a few issues, but I managed to get something like this working.